# How to connect to internet via DSL modem over USB interface?

Tags: 12.04, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my machine.

Please tell me how to connect to internet using ZTE ZXDSL 831 AII modem via USB (not Ethernet) as my ethernet port of modem is damaged.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Is this your [**modem**](http://www.itdunya.com/attachments/148563d1252739235-6.jpg)

Comment: yes, that is exactly my modem.